# Как запустить исполняемый файл для Windows на Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Хотел спросить, в проекте используется `jpegtran.exe` и к нему есть путь, после чего программа обращается к файлу вызывает его и обрабатывает картинку. А если использовать `ubuntu` на сервере этот файл не работает.

Почитал, нашел команды для скачивания, но не пойму почему не работает. Что посоветуете?

Если использовать `ubuntu`, там тоже такой же подход как и у `windows`?
Или код будет другой?

Comment: Если проект ваш - может стоит рассмотреть переход к нативной утилите которая выполняется без извращений с wine? Стоит посмотреть в сторону Imagemagick - он всё это умеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы запустить исполняемые файлы предназначенные для ос `windows` на `linux` существует несколько подходов:

1. Использовать виртуальную машину:  [`virtualBox`](https://www.virtualbox.org), [`mvware`](http://www.vmware.com/ru.html) и пр. c установленной на ней ос `windows`
2. Воспользоваться программой [`wine`](https://www.winehq.org)

Answer (score 0):

Либо воспользуйтесь советом о wine и виртуалке) Либо если программа ваша и есть исходники, то просто скомпелируйте их под ubuntu, возможно понадобятся какие-то изменения в коде, особенно это касается вин форм и directX